# How to get ram size in gb in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to get the ram size of the current machine and the used ram of the current machine in gb.
How do i do this?
I can get the ram size in kB, but how in gb?

```
RAM = $(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo)
```

I would need one variable with the total ram and one with used ram.
I am sorry for this question, but i am editing a bash script for the first time in my life right now ^^
Thanks for all of your Help! ;)

Comment: put a shebang on your code/script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: @Jetchisel: I suspect memory is still measured with the power-of-two values (not the SI power-of-ten ones used by storage manufacturers). Hence, you would probably have to divide by 1024.

Comment: @paxdiablo You're right.

Comment: And how do i divide this by 1024? (which i have to do twice, because it is kB and i need it in gB ;) Just hanging "/1024/1024" on it?
@paxiablo

Comment: See also [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/3266847)

Comment: `awk '/^MemTotal/{print $2/(1024*1024)}' /proc/meminfo` maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want Gibibytes (that is to say using 1024 bytes for Kb, 1024 Kb for Mb, etc), you can do the math yourself, though you'll have to filter the raw number out:

```sh
RAM_KB=$(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
RAM_MB=$(expr $RAM_KB / 1024)
RAM_GB=$(expr $RAM_MB / 1024)
```

You can do basically the same thing for used memory. Alternatively, many systems have the `free` utility installed that does this math for you:

`free -g` will provide the answers in GiB:

```
$ free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             24           0          23           0           1          23
Swap:             7           0           7
```

You can pull the values you need from there with grep and awk:

```
TOTAL_MEM=$(free -g | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2}')
MEM_USED=$(free -g | grep Mem: | awk '{print $3}')
```